# Why does Selenium create a new instance of  RC and/or browser between each JUnit test item?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4

Just starting to experiment with Selenium 2.18.  Why does Selenium create a new instance of "Remote Control" between each JUnit test item?

I created some unit tests called testA, testB, testC  and here is what happens:

```
setUp:
0.  Create static instance of DefaultSelenium

testA:
1.  Selenium starts instance of "Remote Control"
2.  Selenium starts web browser an opens app

testB:
3.  Selenium starts new instance of "Remote Control"
4.  Selenium kills first instance of "Remote Control"
5.  Script sends existing browser to a URL on the local system (probably
    a temp file of some kind)
```

So, my question is, why can't I get Selenium to have only one constant instance of the "Remote Control" and also one constant instance of the Web browser throughout testA, testB, and testC ?

NOTE: step#5 is concerning to me:  if that step didn't redirect to a local file, its possible that the remote control in step#4 might have found content in the page.  Does this happen because the new instance of "Remote Control" doesn't know about the existence of the browser started by the first instance of "Remote Control" ?

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteControlConfiguration;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Tests.class })

public class AllTests {

    static SeleniumServer seleniumserver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        RemoteControlConfiguration settings = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
        settings.setTrustAllSSLCertificates(true);
        seleniumserver=new SeleniumServer(settings);
        seleniumserver.boot();
        seleniumserver.start();
        System.out.println("Finished suite setUpClass");
    }
     ...
```

And for my client:

```
public class Tests extends SeleneseTestBase {
private static DefaultSelenium selenium;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:8181/");
selenium.start();
}

public void testA() {  System.out.println("TestA");  }
public void testB() {  System.out.println("TestB");  }
public void testC() {  System.out.println("TestC");  }
```

Answer (score 3):

It has to be the manner in which you are instantiating the server.
Try invoking your server instance with the `-singleWindow` parameter.

If you are invoking the server programmatically, encapsulate the invocation in the `@Before` annotation.

Here is an example:

```
@Before
public void startServer () throws Exception {
        RemoteControlConfiguration settings = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
        settings.setTrustAllSSLCertificates(true);
        SeleniumServer seleniumserver=new SeleniumServer(settings);
        seleniumserver.boot();
        seleniumserver.start();
...
}
```

Comment: That really really helped me a LOT to improve my setup and teardown but didn't answer my question exactly. Thanks though, for the enlightenment. :-)  Now I use @BeforeClass to setup the server in the Suite class.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does Selenium create a new instance of "Remote Control" between each JUnit test item?

I think this is because you are telling it to. You are creating your selenium object in the setUp() method with the @Before jUnit annotation. This tells jUnit to run that method before every test.

[JUnit API Doc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html?org/junit/Before.html)

Comment: Ahh... I think you might be right.   I'll try creating the browser object in the suite class using the @BeforeClass annotation.

Comment: Give it a try, if you want to maintain the same browser session through your suite of tests you need to make sure you only create a new DefaultSelenium object once.

Answer (score 0):

In selenium 2 this is no longer the case, but in version 1 this was indeed the case. I haven't found a workaround for this.

```
    private DefaultSelenium selenium;

private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    startClient();
    startupHook();
}

protected abstract void startupHook() throws Exception;

private void startClient() {
    String sBrowserType = "*iexplore"; // For Firefox, use *firefox
    this.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, sBrowserType);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    shutdownHook();
    stopClient();
}

protected abstract void shutdownHook() throws Exception;

private void stopClient() {
    if (selenium != null) {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

I added a startup and shutdown hook in case I need to clean up other extra resources.

Comment: I am using Selenium 2 and still having this problem.

Comment: Could you post the way you initialise the remote control?

Comment: What I don't understand is that you're still using the seleniumserver in selenium 2. You can just use webdriver, the internetexplorerdriver/firefoxdriver/htmlunitdriver and the defaultselenium classes. I'll post an answer with how I use selenium 2.

Comment: I tried that and after each test WebDriver closes the browser and then the next test no longer has a handle on the browser instance because it was closed.  It is as if the @Before is something that is ran before each and every test.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post fragment of your code for clarification? And, also let us know if you are using jUnit 4.

In my unit test I have only one selenium browser (aka Selenium Remote control) running for all the test cases.

For each test case you might just want to use .open("the url") function. 
I am initializing selenium remote control only in one place inside setUpBeforeClass() function and closing selenium remote control in tearDownAfterClass()

My answer is based on guesses what wrong you might be doing. I can help you more once I see the code fragment.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. I seem to be required to use the ".open" method at the start of each test case. I am unable to re-use the browser instance and session from the previous test. I purposely try to leave each test at a URL location for the next test to start. So, it seems that requiring "open" is redundant, dont you think? if you are using "open" then I doubt your using the same browser instanced througout your tests.